# Triggering mouse events on static controls

Tags: c, winapi, controls

How can I trigger a mouse drag event on a static control?

---

**Edit:**

Is this how subclassing works? Then how can I add new messages to the window class (mouse click etc.)?

```
WNDPROC wpOrigKnobProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK wpKnobProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        // So here I can receive custom messages for the control?
    }
    return CallWindowProc(wpOrigKnobProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            {
                HWND hctl = CreateWindowEx(0, "STATIC", NULL, SS_CENTERIMAGE | SS_REALSIZEIMAGE | SS_BITMAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 90, 10, 64, 64, hwnd, (HMENU) KNOB, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
                wpOrigKnobProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLong(hctl, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG) wpKnobProc);
            }
            return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'mouse drag event'.  You'll have to sub-class the control.  Record the mouse position in the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message handler and capture the mouse.  Then check it against the current mouse position in the WM_MOUSEMOVE message handler.   It the button is still down and the distance is larger than GetSystemMetrics, SM_CXDOUBLECLK and SM_CYDOUBLECLK then make that your mouse drag event.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But how can I check if the mouse was on the static control (e.g. a text label)?

Comment: Erm, if it isn't on the control then you won't get a mouse message either.

Comment: I get the message when I click anywhere in my main window. The only parameters that the message sends are the mouse x and y positions. Not something like the control that it's currently on.

Comment: Have you subclassed the window yet?

Comment: Well, I never heard of that... Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to take a look at WTL:
CContainedWindow is very handy to SubclassWindow. Manual sub-classing is very messy, but with WTL is a no brainier. In short, it allows you to set your own windowproc that processes window messages that windows sends to controls.

Here's one of the best tutorials for beginners:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/wtl4mfc4.aspx#atl2

Answer (score 0):

If you create a plain static control without any `SS_*` flags, you will probably need to handle `WM_NCHITTEST` in your `wndproc` and return `HTCLIENT`, otherwise you won't get `WM_MOUSExxx` nor `WM_LBUTTON`, etc. messages.